# How to change php code to bind the parameters correctly for inserting multiple instances into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, parameters, bind

After learning how to setup a environment with html, js, ajax, php and mysql I'm able to insert single instances into a table.

I'm trying to get it working with multiple entries into the table for quite a while now. I was reading several documentation pages and recommendations on here but couldn't really figure out what I'm missing.

To clarify: What I'm trying to do is to insert 2 of the same entity. I input `SafetyStock` and `LotSize` of the `Material Pack` thereupon, insert another Material named PET with different

There is no problem with getting the variables from ajax but i don't get the `$stmt->bind_param` line. What do I have to write there to make the code running?

I tried to just have two lines of `stmt` binding, but then it only wrote the last entry into the database. Another thing I did was execute the `stmt` and then overwrite the variables and then do execute again, wasn't working as well.

my actual insert.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "scm";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind settingssupplychaincomponents
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test1 (settingsSupplyChainComponentsId, settingsSupplyChainId, componentId, safetyStockW, lotSizeW) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iiiii", $settingsSupplyChainComponentsId, $settingsSupplyChainId, $pack, $sspack, $lspack); //Pack


// set parameters for components
$settingsSupplyChainComponentsId = '';
$settingsSupplyChainId  = $_POST['ssci'];

// set parameters for pack
$pack = 1;
$sspack = $_POST['sspack'];
$lspack = $_POST['lspack'];

// set parameters for PET
$pet = 2;
$sspet = $_POST['sspet'];
$lspet = $_POST['lspet'];


$values = array();

$stmt->execute($values);






echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The number of variables in `bind_param` has to be the same as the number of `?` in the query.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You only have 5 variables, how do you expect to put them into two rows of the table?

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` doesn't take any arguments, what is `$values` for?

Comment: that makes completely sense. What I'm trying to do is to insert 2 of the same entity. I input SafetyStock and LotSize of the Material Pack thereupon, insert another Material named PET with different numbers but the same variables.

Comment: updated some things in the question post to clarify the procedure

Comment: You mean you want to insert multiple records? Like you have an array of the variables you want to bind? If that's the case, a `foreach` loop is generally recommended. It would help if we knew what you meant by "multiple instances".

Comment: I setup an html page with insert fields for the variables SafetyStock and Lot size for 5 different materials: Pack, PET, Orange, Mango, Vitamin-C. this is a UI to insert the values into the DB to speed up the process of gathering data. so i want to insert multiple records like you mentioned into the table like one entry for Pack one for PET and so on for all 5 Materials

Comment: Yeah you should just insert via a loop. This is considered much better and more performance friendly than trying to generate one giant query.

Comment: In this other Post on here one guy did a little experiment with a loop and all in one query and mentioned it is 8 times faster with the second method. That's why i set it up like this

Comment: Look at the 
example "Example #3 INSERT prepared once, executed multiple times" at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to repeat the variables that should be inserted in both rows.

```
$stmt->bind_param("iiiiiiiiii", 
    $settingsSupplyChainComponentsId, $settingsSupplyChainId, $pack, $sspack, $lspack, 
    $settingsSupplyChainComponentsId, $settingsSupplyChainId, $pet, $sspet, $lspet);
```

Comment: but this wouldn't make 2 entries into the table? this would just make 1 entry with 10 variables?

Comment: Yes it would because you have two lists of values in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Just think of it as replacing each `?` with the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, there was no way of doing multiple entries, instead I used several $stmt, below is an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 SALDOS_DEUDA.FECHA_SALDOS FROM [dbo].[SALDOS_DEUDA]
   WHERE FECHA_SALDOS = (SELECT MAX(FECHA_SALDOS) FROM dbo.SALDOS_DEUDA);";

$sql1 = "SELECT SUM(SALDO_DEUDA) / 1000000 AS SALDO_TOTAL FROM SALDOS_DEUDA
   WHERE FECHA_SALDOS = (SELECT MAX(FECHA_SALDOS) FROM dbo.SALDOS_DEUDA);";

$sql2 = "SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN TIPO_DEUDA = 'E' THEN SALDO_DEUDA ELSE 0 END) / SUM(SALDO_DEUDA)) AS PORCENTAJE_EXTERNO FROM SALDOS_DEUDA 
   WHERE FECHA_SALDOS = (SELECT MAX(FECHA_SALDOS) FROM dbo.SALDOS_DEUDA);";

$sql3 = "SELECT SUM(MONTO) AS TASA_FIJA FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA 
 WHERE ANIO = (SELECT MAX(ANIO) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA)
       AND MES = (SELECT MAX(MES) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA
                   WHERE ANIO = (SELECT MAX(ANIO) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA) )
       AND TIPOTASA_ID = 1;";

$sql4 = "SELECT SUM(MONTO) AS MONEDA_LOCAL FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA 
 WHERE ANIO = (SELECT MAX(ANIO) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA) 
       AND MES = (SELECT MAX(MES) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA 
                   WHERE ANIO = (SELECT MAX(ANIO) FROM dbo.RIESGO_MERCADO_TASA) ) 
       AND MONEDA_ID = 13;";

$sql5 = "SELECT (SUM(P.PROMEDIO * P.SALDO) / SUM(SALDO)) AS CPP
          FROM dbo.PROMEDIO_PONDERADO P
               INNER JOIN dbo.CG_CATEGORIA_PONDERADO C ON P.CATEGORIA_ID = C.CATEGORIA_ID
         WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM dbo.PROMEDIO_PONDERADO)
               AND C.TIPO = 1;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql3);
$stmt4 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql4);
$stmt5 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql5);
```